# IPv6: Router Advertisement only works for 8 seconds

Tags: router, ipv6

(I already asked this in the IPFire forum but didn't get an answer)

I have setup a native IPv6 connection using a bridge as documented in http://wiki.ipfire.org/en/add-ipv6/ipv6/extended. 
IP addresses (and the prefix) are handed out by a separate DHCPv6 server.
radvd is running on IPFire to send out router advertisements so the clients get the gateway they should use to connect outside.

```
radvd configuration:
interface green0 {
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    AdvManagedFlag on;
};
```

When I restart radvd, my Windows 7 client gets some router advertisements (proposing the link-local address of the green interface) and inbetween the ping first works, then fails, and is ok again after the next RA arrives:

```
Ping wird ausgeführt für ipv6.l.google.com [2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003] mit 32 Bytes Daten:
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=16ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=16ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=17ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=16ms
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=175ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=16ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=16ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=16ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=16ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=21ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=16ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=16ms
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=201ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=16ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=16ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=16ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=16ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=16ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=16ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=16ms
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=200ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=16ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=16ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=16ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=16ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=17ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=23ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=30ms
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=201ms
Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=32ms
Antwort von 2a00:1450:4001:80a::1003: Zeit=17ms
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
Zielhost nicht erreichbar.
```

It then fails until the next RA arrives. I can minimize the problem by setting `MinRtrAdvInterval` and `MaxRtrAdvInterval` to lower values. Though, it will still fail sometimes and some pings will have high response times.

I already found out that I can workaround the problem by manually configuring a static IPv6 address for my client and setting the gateway to the link-local address of the bridge instead of the green interface. Though, this is no solution as that address will change with the next reboot.

Therefore, I use the global address that is configured to the bridge. Aside from the fact, that not using a link-local address is probably unclean, the problem is that I don't want to configure every client in our network manually.

Can someone please tell me why my client apparently loses the router information after 7-8 seconds???
Is there a way to configure radvd to send out the static global address in it's router advertisement (in case this is sane)?

Comment: What does `netsh interface ipv6 show address level=verbose` show? How about `netsh int ipv6 sho route verbose`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/F7KCQ25S

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0Tk0jVHH

Comment: In case I should translate it into English please let me know. There is no difference in outpus when the ping is ok vs when the ping fails.